# 220 hot tub / spa breaker question

Tags: subpanel, hot-tub

[image]Ok......  I had an older spa pump that went out.  I also replaced the spa pack. The old spa pack had a GFCI breaker in it and the new one does not.  So now I have to add gfci protection to the spa via a gfci breaker.  The older main panel (square D) does not make gfci breakers for that style of panel (1980's).  So I elminated the hot tub from the main and moved it into an under utilized already existing sub panel.

Here is where I am now lost..... the sub has only one bus bar, all wired attached are grounds, there is NO floating neutral bus bar. I know I can NOT run the breaker (which has a built in "coiled" neutral wire to the ground bus bar or I create a parallel circuit which will feed back current and will not trip the gfci.

So.......
Question 1:  Can I ground the hot tub in the subpanel and run the neutral into the main panel and attach it there ?  Will that create a parallel circuit?  Will that prevent the gfci breaker from tripping?

Question 2:  If that will not work....... OPTION A: is there a way to ground the subpanel, (grounding rod) and mount a new bus bar to ground box and use the other bus bar as a neutral bar.  OR OPTION B: how do I create a neutral bus bar in the subpanel...... (if this is the option I need details) I know it needs to float, but where would it connect to in the main panel ? What gauge wire would be needed?

More info..... the main panel does not have a Main disconnect breaker, the sub panel is being fed from a 60 AMP breaker in the main panel that has two wires from the breaker to the subpanel lugs, a ground and a neutral in the main panel.
The current subpanel (also Square D) bus is a ground bus running to the main panel bus.

Thank you for any and all information, I am NO electrician so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused... How many wires are there between the panels, 3 or 4? Are all the wires insulated, or are there one or more bare wires?  What color is the insulation that is on the wires? Where are the wires terminated in the main, and where are they terminated in the second panel?  Photos would help.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to run a grounded (neutral) conductor between the panels, and install a grounded (neutral) bar in the second panel. But I can't be sure based on your description.

Comment: Just added a picture.  The orientation is incorrect but this should help, I hope.  There only appears to be two (2) hots feeding the subpanel. There does not appear to even be a ground.

Comment: This was a subpanel for a/c handlers prior to us upgrading the house to a gas pack and thus this panel became useless, until now.

Comment: Like @Tester101 said, you need 4 conductors from the main panel to the sub (2 "hot", 1 grounded/"neutral," and 1 green or bare grounding conductor).  Looking at your picture, that bus bar on plastic standoffs in the lower right (upper right if you rotate the picture) is the neutral bar **if** you remove that brass bonding screw that is connecting it to the panel. So you'll also need to install a grounding bus bar, bonded to the panel, and connect the neutrals and grounding wires to their separate bus. Grounded (neutral) and grounding **must** be isolated in a sub-panel (bonded in main panel).

Comment: You also need to fix or replace that gray PVC liquidtight conduit that's broken at the connection to the panel.  ;-)

Comment: Based on the picture I do not have the neutral nor the ground from the sub to the main.  Do I get a "naked" copper wire and run it to the main panel bus bar from the bonded panel I install in the sub and where does the white neutral wire go from the floating bus bar in the sub to the main? Also, where do I pull the ground and neutral from in the main to go to the sub that currently are not there from the 60 amp breaker in the main?

Comment: @Robert Can you read the printing on the black wires feeding the panel, and tell us what size they are?  There should be a number followed by "AWG". It should also say if it's copper (CU) or aluminum (AL), which we'll need to know.

Comment: Can I get the bonded bus from a big box retailer like Lowes? Do I need to connect the bonded bus to the bus in the main or do I need to run a separate grounding rod?

Comment: I do not see an awg "rating"  which I thought all wire was required to have, it does say, " water and oil resistant 600v copper wire ", but that is all.

Comment: It is not solid wire but strand wire

Comment: Solid vs stranded isn't an issue (unless there is corrosion amongst the strands where the end of the wire is exposed). The biggest conductors (main service feeders) are generally always stranded. 600v is a standard rating. Small wires are good for 600v as well, but bigger wire can carry more current (Amps) safely. @Tester101 is asking for the wire size to determine what size main breaker is appropriate in the subpanel. Al wire needs to be bigger than Cu for the same load, and Al also requires special care at connections.

Comment: Once the ground bus bar is attached do I run a ground from the new bus bar back to the one in the Main box?  and once I remove the screw from the bus bar that already exists and make it a floating bar, do I run a wire to anything in the main panel (like the bus bar there) ? or do I just leave it as is and "by its self"

Comment: This is covered in the answer @Tester101 gave. You do need to run a ground wire from the new grounding bus (which must be bonded to the panel) back to the grounding bus in the main panel, and a grounded (neutral) wire back to the grounded/neutral bus in the main panel, and ensure that those *and* the "hot" conductors are appropriately sized (#6 AWG, if you're keeping that 50A breaker). The grounded/neutral and grounding buses will (must) be electrically bonded in the main panel. But if it's already organized with neutral and grounding wires on their own buses, do the same with your new wires.

Comment: Just a final note--looking at your picture, there are some ground wires poking so far through the clamps in that bus bar that they're touching (or nearly touching) the side of the panel. You want to be sure you don't do that with the neutral wires you connect there after you remove the brass bonding screw. If the ends of those wires touch the panel, you'll be bonding your grounded (neutral) and grounding conductors in the subpanel, which is against code.

Comment: **One more** final note that occurs to me--if you're going to do this yourself and you need a fish tape and you haven't purchased or rented one yet, really consider getting one made of fiberglass instead of metal. Electricians will blanket the buses in a panel (literally cover them with insulating material) before pushing a metal fish tape into them. You definitely want to do the same and/or use a non-conductive fish tape.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate the help.  Added a grounded bus bar to the new panel, moved the grounds over to it. Removed the brass screw and ran the neutral to it.  Confirmed the 2 hots were 4 awg CU wire.  Ran 6 awg wire from the neutral bus bar sub to the neutral bus bar main and did the same with the ground.  I really appreciate Craig and Tester101 for the assistance.  Spa is running as per the way it is supposed to....... much THANKS gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from the photo if there's even a grounding conductor run along with the two ungrounded (hot) conductors, so you'll have to verify that before you go shopping for supplies. You'll also have to verify that the ungrounded (hot) conductors are the proper size. You said the panel is fed through a 60 ampere breaker, so you'll need at least 6 AWG copper conductors (solid or stranded, it makes no difference).

### Shopping

Here's what you're going to need.

- A grounding bus bar.
- 6 AWG copper THWN wire with white or gray insulation, long enough to reach from the main grounded (neutral) bar to second panel grounded (neutral) bar.
- 6 AWG bare or green copper conductor, long enough to reach from the main grounding bar to the second panel grounding bar (which you'll install).

If the current ungrounded (hot) conductors are undersized, you have a couple choices. You can replace them, with appropriate conductors.  Or you can install a smaller feeder breaker in the main panel, and down size the grounded and grounding conductors accordingly.

### Installation

Once you have the supplies, here's what you're going to do.

- Remove the brass bonding screw from the existing bus bar in the second panel.
- Install the grounding bus bar (the one you purchased), in the panel.
- Move all the grounding conductors from the old grounding bus, to the new grounding bus bar.
- Pull the required conductors between the panels.
- Connect the grounded (neutral) conductor to the grounded (neutral) bar in the main panel.
- Connect the grounding conductor to the grounding bar in the main panel.
- Connect the grounded (neutral) conductor to the grounded (neutral) bar in the second panel.
- Connect the grounding conductor to the new grounding bar in the second panel.
- Connect the grounded (neutral) pigtail from the GFCI breaker, to the grounded (neutral) bar in the second panel.

Now you should be all set.

***NOTE:** Depending on where the second panel is installed. You may need to install a grounding electrode, and bond the panel to it.  Check with your local building department, to determine if this is required.*